# Export Lucene results/output files

Tags: java, file, lucene, data-mining

I have a dataset which has around 10,000 emails which are in txt format. The dataset has around 4k fraudulent emails and 6k non-fraudulent emails. I am using Lucene to cluster this (Fraudulent and non-fraudulent).

For example, For input query search = "spam", I get around 600 files matching the string. 
My problem here is, I want to copy or export the result files to another folder.
This is my output when I give the search string="spam"

```
File name: C:\21 march\data\6724.txt Score: 0.24614158
File name: C:\21 march\data\6308.txt Score: 0.24614158
File name: C:\21 march\data\375.txt Score: 0.19691327
File name: C:\21 march\data\4630.txt Score: 0.14768496
Found 600
```

I want to export or copy these files from this location to another location - say `C:\Answer\data\62724.txt`. Is it possible to copy these clustered files to another folder?

Comment: What's preventing you from doing this?

Comment: **Yes**. It is easy to copy these files to another folder? Where is your problem with doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the question?

You are in Java. Java has functions to copy files.

Read the tutorial on essential file I/O (file copying), then copy the files you want into your output folder.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

Comment: I got the answer before reading this. I checked the Java I/O methods. I was just looking if Lucene could do that or not. Thanks :)